# My original Size will change after combined Two images into one Image

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiimageview

I want to combined Two images and my BaseImages Size is 1280*1920  then i used method to convert into 1 image, but the new image Size will be 320*480.
i want its original pixel And Size

i used this Code :

```
//  ImageContainView  - UIView that Contains 2 UIImageView. View size :- 320*480

UIImage *temp;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageContainView.bounds.size);
[imageContainView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
temp = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

[image: Base image Size 1280*1920]

Comment: what on the earth do you want? Whats your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, the reason you are getting a small image is that you are initializing your context with a small size:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageContainView.bounds.size);
```

if `imageContainView.bounds.size` is 320x480, you will get a 320x480 image.

So, you should call:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(correctImageSize);
```

where `correctImageSize` is CGSizeMake(1280,1920), or the size of the bigger image you have.

Or you could try calling `sizeToFit` before:

```
[imageContainView sizeToFit];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageContainView.bounds.size);
```